# Display Video Inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have video embedded in a webpage. 
I would like to let it play inline on the iOS and not expanding to full screen when clicking on the play button.

I've tried

adding `webkit-playsinline`

```
<video width="400" controls webkit-playsinline>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I've tried added in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/n8nungdm/2/show) <-- Please View it use your Phone/Tablet

Any hints ?

Comment: I found this: "The webkit-playsinline attribute works for HTML5 video on iOS4+ but only when you save the webpage to your home screen as a webapp. If you are using mobile Safari it will always open fullscreen".

Comment: Didn't remember the web app exception, but @makshh is right, on iPhone (though not on iPad), you cannot play a video inline in Safari. It will always open full screen (and never auto-start on either type of device).

Comment: Try this reference - http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the following in Obj C as well.

```
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

Your existing attribute is right like below.

```
<video id="player" width="480" height="320" webkit-playsinline>
```

#### Other - Use HTML5 FullScreen API

http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Below are the Webkit Fullscreen properties to play around.

1. document.webkitCurrentFullScreenElement
2. document.webkitCancelFullScreen
3. document.webkitFullScreenKeyboardInputAllowed
4. document.webkitIsFullScreen

Comment: Where do I set this `webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;` ?

Comment: Try this jsfiddle and try cancelfullscreen in webkit condition !

Comment: Where is your Fiddle link ? I don't see it.

Comment: its my bad. look at this url http://darktalker.com/2014/05/play-video-inline-iphone-ios7/